# Getting "Sorry, I didn't get any response." message when I tried Hand-off feature

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

When I tried Multi-surface conversations (Hand-off from Google Home to Android Google Assistant), I'm getting "Sorry, I didn't get any response."
I'm using Action SDK and locale is "ja".

Here is my response:

```
{
    "conversationToken": "(token)",
    "expectUserResponse": true,
    "isInSandbox": true,
    "expectedInputs": [
        {
            "possibleIntents": [
                {
                    "intent": "actions.intent.NEW_SURFACE",
                    "inputValueData": {
                        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.NewSurfaceValueSpec",
                        "context": "Sure, I have some sample images for you.",
                        "notificationTitle": "Sample Images",
                        "capabilities": [
                            "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "inputPrompt": {
                "richInitialPrompt": {
                    "items": {
                        "simpleResponse": {
                            "textToSpeech": "PLACEHOLDER_FOR_NEW_SURFACE"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: The original post above is that he uses the Actions SDK. When I use the "Dialogflow" and the app.askForNewSurface() function in the "ja-JP" locale, I get same response "Sorry, I didn't get any response." from Google Assistant. However, in the "en-US" locale, I can get a correct response from Assistant as "Is it okay if I send that to your phone?". It seems that this is a bug in the "ja-jp" locale only, probably...

Comment: @YoichiroTanaka ok, I added dialogflow tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that this is not a bug in a certain locale, but that askForNewSurface is currently supported for english locales only.
This is what I got from AoG support:

> Hi Jan,
>
> Thank you for your interest in Actions on Google.
>   askForNewSurface is indeed only available for English locales. We are in the process of changing the documentation to reflect those restrictions.
>   Sorry for the confusion.
>   We do not have any set det for the release of this feature in other locales.
>
> Kind Regards,
>
> Jean-Charles,
>   Actions on Google Support Team.

Comment: Thanks fo the info! I was skeptical that ja does not support handoff feature yet, but this proved  that it was true.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be available only in english but i find no clear statement about this on any documentation.

I tried the exact same code in english and in french, it works in english, not in french.