# Google Assistant changing the surface not working

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, dialogflow-es

Hi guys,

I'm currently trying to build an app for the Google Assistant with Dialogflow. During a particular intent I want to redirect the user to his phone (when using a speaker) as the intent requires precise keyboard input.
As said in the docs, I'm calling `askForNewSurface()` in my webhook. In the actions simulator, this is what shows up (truncated)

```
"agentToAssistantJson": {
  "conversationToken": "[\"_actions_on_google_\",\"some-context\"]",
  "expectUserResponse": true,
  "expectedInputs": [
    {
      "inputPrompt": {
        "richInitialPrompt": {
          "items": [
            {
              "simpleResponse": {
                "textToSpeech": "PLACEHOLDER_FOR_NEW_SURFACE"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "possibleIntents": [
        {
          "intent": "actions.intent.NEW_SURFACE",
          "inputValueData": {
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.NewSurfaceValueSpec",
            "context": "To show you an image",
            "notificationTitle": "Check out this image",
            "capabilities": [
              "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "responseMetadata": {
    "status": {},
    "queryMatchInfo": {
      "queryMatched": true,
      "intent": "####",
      "parameterNames": [
        "date"
      ]
    }
  },
  "expectedInput": {
    "requestedIntent": {
      "intent": "####"
    }
  }
}
```

}

This seems valid according to the docs, however the Google Assistant just comes back with 'Sorry, I didn't get any response' (on both the simulator and on actual devices).

*So how do I get the assistant to actually ask the user to change the surface?*

Is this method maybe not supported at all in german? Also the docs are somewhat inconsistent regarding the existence of `actions.intent.NEW_SURFACE` as a system intent...

Thanks in advance guys, any hints appreciated :)

EDIT: Noticed the question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47403159/getting-sorry-i-didnt-get-any-response-message-when-i-tried-hand-off-featur)

Comment: I tried it too, but not working for me as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I got in touch with AoG support. Turns out we'll need a little patience.

> Hi Jan,
>
> Thank you for your interest in Actions on Google. askForNewSurface is indeed only available for English locales. We are in the process of changing the documentation to reflect those restrictions.
>   Sorry for the confusion.
>   We do not have any set date for the release of this feature in other locales.
>
> Kind Regards,
>
> Jean-Charles,
>
> Actions on Google Support Team.