# Actions On Google askForNewSurface not switching

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, google-home

I'm using the actions on google nodejs library to use askForNewSurface to switch to a device with a screen when I need to send information in a card.

My problem is that askForNewSurface appears to run successfully but the conversation never switches to another device.

[Actions on google simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bp8Do.png)

This occurs both in the actions on google simulator and on actual google home devices, the device states that they'll switch and ends the conversation but nothing happens after.

This is the code I'm using to prompt the switch:

```
const hasScreen = app.hasAvailableSurfaceCapabilities(app.SurfaceCapabilities.SCREEN_OUTPUT);
if (hasScreen) {
    app.data.newSurfaceTransfer = cardData;
    app.askForNewSurface(cardData.sendToScreenMessage, cardData.sendToScreenContext, [app.SurfaceCapabilities.SCREEN_OUTPUT]);
}
```

I'm aware of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47610115/google-assistant-changing-the-surface-not-working) and I don't believe it applies in my situation because I'm testing this in english (united states).

These are my dependency versions

```
"@types/node": "^9.3.0",
"actions-on-google": "^1.7.0",
"body-parser": "^1.18.2",
"dotenv": "^4.0.0",
"express": "^4.16.2",
"firebase": "^4.8.1",
"nodemon": "^1.14.10",
"request": "^2.81.0",
"rx-http-request": "^1.2.0",
"rxjs": "^5.5.6"
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance or guidance!

Comment: Can you post an image of the entire simulator screen? (Obscuring anything sensitive, but trying to show as much as possible.) Posting the contents of the Debug, Request, and Response tabs will also help.

Comment: Make sure you have Notifications enabled in the Google Assistant settings of the device you're trying to switch to.

Comment: @Bart You were absolutely, and almost painfully, right.  I'd turned off notifications for the google app when I first got my phone because it had been bugging me.  Notifications still don't come through on the simulator but do work on actual google home devices, which is grand.

Comment: Thank you very much too @Prisoner, I was going to do exactly that had notification settings not turned out to be the issue!

Comment: And as a correction for above, notifications now do work on the simulator.  Thank you both again!

Comment: Good call! My guess was that you were testing it using the Phone emulator, and if you say to send it to the phone, from a phone, it won't necessarily work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Bart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8752783/bart), [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48172336/actions-on-google-askfornewsurface-not-switching#comment83344947_48172336) above, made the correct assessment.  I had turned off notifications for the google app on my phone.